# Upgrading Greenplum DB that includes PostGIS extension

Tags: upgrade, postgis, greenplum

We've got a number of 4.2.3.2 Greenplum databases that are running PostGIS 1.4.  We are trying to get these databases onto a more recent version of Greenplum, such as 4.3.8.1 or the re-released version of 4.3.9.1, but we're running into a mess of issues when attempting to upgrade PostGIS to version 2.0.  We've attempted a number of different ways to upgrade the database without compromising data and functions that rely on PostGIS 1.4, but it looks like when we run the [gppkg](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/install_guide/refs/gppkg.html) utility with the new PostGIS extensions we only get errors, similar to the following:

```
gppkg -i postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg 
20160919:13:21:20:024675 gppkg:s-md-pv-gp-01-01:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Starting gppkg with args: -i postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg
20160919:13:21:20:024675 gppkg:s-md-pv-gp-01-01:gpadmin-[CRITICAL]:-gppkg failed. (Reason='__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'postupdate'') exiting...
```

We've also run gppkg passing the -u flag, with similar results:

```
gppkg -u postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg 
20160919:13:35:52:024930 gppkg:s-md-pv-gp-01-01:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Starting gppkg with args: -u postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg
20160919:13:35:52:024930 gppkg:s-md-pv-gp-01-01:gpadmin-[WARNING]:-WARNING: The process of updating a package includes removing all
20160919:13:35:52:024930 gppkg:s-md-pv-gp-01-01:gpadmin-[WARNING]:-previous versions of the system objects related to the package. For
20160919:13:35:52:024930 gppkg:s-md-pv-gp-01-01:gpadmin-[WARNING]:-example, previous versions of shared libraries are removed.
20160919:13:35:52:024930 gppkg:s-md-pv-gp-01-01:gpadmin-[WARNING]:-After the update process, a database function will fail when it is
20160919:13:35:52:024930 gppkg:s-md-pv-gp-01-01:gpadmin-[WARNING]:-called if the function references a package file that has been removed.
Do you still want to continue ? Yy|Nn (default=N):
> y
20160919:13:35:59:024930 gppkg:s-md-pv-gp-01-01:gpadmin-[CRITICAL]:-gppkg failed. (Reason='__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'postupdate'') exiting...
```

A major caveat may also be related to the fact that only [Greenplum versions 4.2.6.X to 4.2.8.X support both version 1.4 and 2.0 of postGIS](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4340/ref_guide/postGIS.html).  At this point, we're looking for some direction on how to proceed in hopes others may have come up against some of these hurdles.

We've got tickets in with the vendor, Pivotal, but these are not proving fruitful so I'm posting here in hopes the community has some direction they can point me in.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade path we have identified is the very definition of [kludgy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kludgy), but it looks to get all the data over with an end result of both an upgraded database and upgraded PostGIS extension.  The (admittedly Rube Goldberg-ish) steps are as follows and are required for every database on the server being upgraded containing PostGIS data:

1. `pg_dump` all tables containing PostGIS related data *for every database on the server*
2. drop all tables containing PostGIS related data (same that were just backed up) for *databases that had PostGIS tables in **step 1***
3. run `unstall_postgis.sql` script in `$GPHOME/share/postgrestql/contrib` against *databases that had PostGIS tables in **step 1***
4. Uninstall PostGIS 1.0 gppkg (`%> gppkg -r postgis-1.0`)
5. Upgrade GreenPlum database via the [gpmigrator/gpmigrator_mirrors](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/utility_guide/admin_utilities/gpmigrator.html) standard process
6. Install PostGIS 2.0 gppkg (`%> gppkg -i postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg`)
7. run `postgis.sql` script in `$GPHOME/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.0` against *each database that had PostGIS tables in **step 1***
8. `pg_restore` *all tables exported in **step 1***

We are also including some steps not listed here on an intermediate server to avoid an in-place upgrade so we have a quick recovery point.  The process is a bit cumbersome, but so far testing seems to indicate it is working without any obvious issues.

Hopefully this helps someone out in the future,

John

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that the `postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg` package has a bug and it does not have implemented the `postupdate` as defined in the [Gppkg class](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/blob/5e42b17311681d091ba1c8b3fcf65c4b4c9b9a17/gpMgmt/bin/gppylib/operations/package.py). The TAG is optional `(SPECFILE_OPTIONAL_TAGS = ... 'postupdate'] )` so it looks like it is calling

Check if the upgrade script ($GPHOME/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.0/postgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql) exists in that location. [Package details](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/blob/d9e94bc1331958b7b5bb486202aed41f0f55cd60/gpAux/extensions/postgis-2.0.3/package/gppkg_spec.yml.in).

From that specification:

```
PostUpdate:
10  - Master: "echo 'Please run psql -d mydatabase -f 
$GPHOME/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.0/postgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql 
to finish the update.'"
```

Also, you may want to try the `--clean` option

Comment: That script exists and the `--clean` flag didn't do the trick either, so I suspect you are correct about the gppkg having a bug contained within it.  Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: Seeing as the bounty is coming up for expiration and you were the only response, I'm going to send it your way by default.  Better that someone gets it rather then it go to waste.  I'll post our upgrade path as I think we've got something workable... just not pretty.

Comment: Thank you @JohnEisbrener!! At least I did more progress than GP support :p